# How to pass the props dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to learn how to use react-polls (for further communication with backend, so, some fragments of my code are prepared for next steps). The problem is: I expect to see 123 in my browser (as in componentDidMount), but I don't.

When I pass the string '123' directly instead of `const pollQuestion = props => (<div>{props.quest}</div>);` it works.

```
//imports

import Poll from 'react-polls';


const pollQuestion = props => (<div>{props.quest}</div>);

const pollAnswers = [
  { option: 'Yes', votes: 8 },
  { option: 'No', votes: 2 }
]

class PollQuestion extends Component {
  state = {
    pollAnswers: [...pollAnswers]
  }

  handleVote = voteAnswer => {
    const { pollAnswers } = this.state
    const newPollAnswers = pollAnswers.map(answer => {
      if (answer.option === voteAnswer) answer.votes++
      return answer
    })
    this.setState({
      pollAnswers: newPollAnswers
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { pollAnswers } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Poll question={pollQuestion} answers={pollAnswers} onVote={this.handleVote} />
        <p>It works</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class QuestionList extends Component {
    state = {
        questions: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
                this.setState({ questions: [{question_text:'123'}]});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>{this.state.questions?
                <ul>
                    <PollQuestion quest={this.state.questions.slice(0, 1).map(question => <li>{question.question_text}</li>)} />
                </ul>:null}
            </div>
        )
    }
};


function AppV() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QuestionList/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppV;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was you were not passing the value of this.props.quest to the pollQuestion element. Either do this

```
<Poll question={this.props.quest} answers={pollAnswers} onVote={this.handleVote} />
```

See code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nngrut

OR do this

```
Edit 
const pollQuestion = props => (<div>{props.quest}</div>); to
const MyPollQuestion  = props => (<div>{props.quest}</div>);

<Poll question={<MyPollQuestion quest={this.props.quest} />} answers={pollAnswers} onVote={this.handleVote} />
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxf2kx?file=AppV.js

Also, All react components should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score -1):

The

> React-Polls question attribute has Proptype of string

and you are

> trying to pass a React Element

to it that is why it is not working.

Pass you question string directly.

Comment: it can accept elements. check here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nngrut

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Which component are you talking about.

Comment: the question rendered is an <li>, you could pass elements and not just strings

Comment: @DhananjaiPai The issue is because of react-polls question prop, Check the code for proptype. I think you misunderstood the question. https://github.com/viniciusmeneses/react-polls/blob/master/src/index.js#L19

Comment: const Test = (props) => <li>{props.quest}</li>;

        <Poll question={<Test quest="123" />}

Run this. it will still work

Comment: for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxf2kx?file=AppV.js

Comment: In my case, it complained initially like that: _'Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `question` of type `object` supplied to `Poll`, expected `string`...'_, maybe this is a reason why someone can think that the string type was a problem.

Comment: My bad I missed out that he did not initialise the pollQuestion component, straight away jumped to "passing string is working and component is not". :)